# Need to get "default_billing" value from window.customerData object in js file magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer, shipping

How to get `default_billing` value from `window.customerData` object in js file `magento 2`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for get billing and shipping address.

```
class SetCustomer {
    protected $_customerFactory;
    protected $_addressFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
                                \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    }

    //get customer model before you can get its address data
    $customer = $customerFactory->create()->load(1);    //insert customer id

    //billing
    $billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
    $billingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($billingAddressId);
    //now you can update your address here and don't forget to save
    $billingAddress->save();

    //shipping
    $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
    $shippingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($shippingAddressId);
    //now you can update your address here and don't forget to save
    $shippingAddress->save();
```

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Thank you , but i want to get that value into js file.